# Client send ws://[host]:[port]/path to server, and my server is Nginx+uwsgi+Django,But I always meet 404 error when I launch get to server

Tags: django, nginx, websocket, uwsgi

Websocket cannot be accpeted by Nginx+Uwsgi to my Django
I use Django write some url_patterns such as

```
http://[host]:[port]/events
```

And I need to handle one websocket

```
<ws://[host]:[port]/alarm>
```

Nginx listen 10001 and uwsgi listen 10002
I have add some to my nginx.conf

```
server
    {
        listen 10001;
        root  /xxx;

        location /alarm {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:10002;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
        location / {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:10002;
            uwsgi_read_timeout 60;
        }
    ......
```

but it still not work and when I see the brower I see this

### `Status Code:404 Not Found`

I choose uwsgi to achieve my websocket, and in my test I write this

```
ws.create_connection("ws://127.0.0.1:10001/alarm")
```

And I use this to launch my app

```
uwsgi --init uwsgi.ini --http_websockets
```

And I see this in uwsgi output

```
GET /alarm => generated 77 bytes in 6 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 6 headers in 207 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

And web_client.py gives me errors below

```
Handshaken 404
```

My uwsgi.ini is this

```
WEBSOCKET_FACTORY_CLASS="dwebsocket.backends.uwsgi.factory.uWsgiWebSocketFactory"
http = :8008
socket = :10002
```

In my django, I write this

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket':AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            alarm.routing.channel_routing
        )
    ),
```

So where my wrongs?

Comment: If this block is a reverse proxy, you are missing the `proxy_pass` statement.

Comment: How does your uwsgi.ini file look like?

Comment: @Hexy I have updated my question and I have no idea right now ...

Comment: @RichardSmith Now I use this , In my uwsgi I wrote `socket :10002` and in nginx I wrote this `uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:10002` but I am still wrong

Comment: I see in your uwsgi.ini file both `http = :8008` &
`socket = :10002` 

- Nginx <--> uwsgi can talk uwsgi protocol. If you say `socket:10002`, that means you are asking nginx & uwsgi to use this unix socket to talk in uwsgi protocol

- The docs have a format for using websocket: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WebSockets.html#routing 
`[uwsgi]
route = ^/websocket http:127.0.0.1:10002 `

Comment: As @RichardSmith suggested, you are trying to use nginx as a websocket proxy. So you have to add the `proxy_pass` statement. `location /alarm/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:10002;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
}`